# Silverlight 4 smooth IIS client, multiple angle/videos, one player

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, smooth-streaming-player

I currently have a Silverlight 4 solution that displays 3 different pre-recorded angles of the same event.  I’m using 3 different SmoothStreamingMediaElement components to display the various angles.  I’ve written my own fast forward/rewind functionality and keep the various videos in sync through custom code.

I’m now looking for a better way to accomplish this task vs. my own custom solution.  I’ve searched the internet for an elegant solution and I’m unable to find one.

Are there any solutions/examples available which allow me to simultaneously stream multiple videos in on player?

Thanks!